# How to configure Swift helper app to not include the same frameworks as the main app?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm shipping a macOS app that includes a helper Cocoa app (LSUIElement, i.e. a menu bar app). They work well together, but I want to get rid of the duplicate frameworks to reduce the download size.

Currently, the helper contains all libswift frameworks and shared 3rd party frameworks in its app bundle. I'd like the helper's `Contents/Frameworks/` directory to not include the stuff of the main app just a few path changes away.

Can one achieve this at all, loading frameworks from the parent app's directory, and if so, how?